# Inverse conditions

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I'm trying to rephrase the a conditional to drop a `{ .. }` statement (to make the code less indented).

Currently I have:

```
while($something){
  if((strcasecmp($str1, $str2)  === 0)
     || (isset($arr[0]) && strcasecmp($str3, $str4) === 0)){

    // a lot of code here...
    break;
  }
}
```

With the inversed IF condition it should look like:

```
while($something){
  if((strcasecmp($str1, $str2) !== 0)
     && (empty($arr[0]) && strcasecmp($str3, $str4) !== 0))
       continue;
  // a lot of code here...
  break;
}
```

But it doesn't work. My code and the break statement get executed when they shouldn't.

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't refactor your code to get rid of the `{ .. }`.  Refactor if it is causing a problem, if it increases readability etc, but neither really apply in this case.

Comment: An easy way to get inversed condition is doing `!(oldconditions)`

Comment: What is the `break` good for? As far as I can see `while($x) { /*..*/ break; }` is the same as `if ($x) { /*..*/ }` :?

Comment: @KingCrunch haha that should be the answer ^_^ i did not even notice that silliness lol

Comment: @KingCrunch What if `$something` is `$arr = $stmt->fetch()` ?

Comment: @Alfwed Put parenthesis around it? What should happen then? :? It doesn't change anything as long as `while(){break;}` is just a curious `if`-statement

Comment: The while loop will break only when the specific condition is met. It  will not break immediatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
(empty($arr[0]) && strcasecmp($str3, $str4) !== 0))
```

The `&&` must be `||`.

I for myself would keep the first variant, because it's slightly more straight-forward.

Update: OK, as I thought about it the `break;` makes me wonder. You want to get rid of one intendation?

```
if ($something 
    && ((strcasecmp($str1, $str2)  === 0) || (isset($arr[0]) && strcasecmp($str3, $str4)) === 0)
){

    // a lot of code here...
}
```

And know some micro-optimization :) (`!strcasecmp()` means, that they *are* equal, except maybe the case)

```
if ($something && (!strcasecmp($str1, $str2) || (isset($arr[0]) && !strcasecmp($str3, $str4))) {

    // a lot of code here...
}
```

I hope the paranthesis matches.

Comment: [:-P](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670053/inverse-conditions#comment15467915_11670053)

Comment: Be careful. `empty` is not the same as `!isset`. Indeed `empty(0)` is true but `!isset(0)` is false

Comment: @Alfwed You are right, but I've taken the not-refactored variant, thus this one should work like expected.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
while($something){
  if((strcasecmp($str1, $str2) !== 0)
     && (!isset($arr[0]) || strcasecmp($str3, $str4) !== 0))
       continue;
  // a lot of code here...
  break;
}
```